# find int in string

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, int

Ok if I have an string input of     "3           6"

how do I put those two int in an array? what if you have more than one spaces between them?

let's say I want those numbers to be in an array like {3, 6}
is that possible? thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using a regular expression to split the input string whenever a sequence of one or more spaces is found, and then convert the resulting `String[]` to an `int[]`:

```
String numberString = "  1   2 34    7 ";
String[] numbers = numberString.split("\\s+");
int[] ints = new int[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
```

Now the `ints` array contains the expected values:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
> [1, 2, 34, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "3 6 4 879";
preg_match_all('/\d+(?=\s*)/', $string, $arr);
```

Here's a PHP way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can used with split for your problem for example :

Program that splits on spaces [C#]

```
static void Main()

{
string s = "1 3 2 7";
//
// Split string on spaces.
// ... This will separate all the words.
//
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
}
```

Output

1
3
2
7

Comment: I think he wants them as ints so you'll need to parse those strings to int in C#.

Comment: but for @Leaf C. problem yes you right my sample need a convert .

Comment: thank you for your help! but what if I have more than one space between those number? what should i do?

Comment: You'll end up getting numbers with spaces in the front. There's a trim function for strings in Java. I don't remember it off the top of my head, but you can find it. It'll get rid of the extra whitespace after splitting.

Comment: @Leaf C. But arnt you using java

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(mString);
while (sc.hasNextInt()){
    mArrayList.add(sc.nextInt())
}
```

Then just convert the ArrayList back to an array.